# UTM – Must Be Superuser To Use Mount When Trying To Automatically Mount the Share on Start

Tags: linux, mount, kali-linux, virtual-machine, fstab

I am new to virtual machines and have set up a Kali VM on my new M2 MacBook through UTM. I have set a shared drive up through virtiofs so I can transfer files between the two machines. I can mount the share fine using:

```
sudo mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio share /home/core/Shared -oversion=9p2000.L
```

However, when trying to mount automatically on start as mentioned [here](https://docs.getutm.app/guest-support/linux/#macos-virtiofs) in the UTM docs, I get an error saying "Failed to mount Shared: must be superuser to mount". How do I fix this? I have put `share /home/core/Shared virtiofs rw,nofail 0 0` into my `/etc/fstab` and have run `sudo chown -R $USER /home/core/Shared`. Do I have to somehow run the `mount` as a superuser on startup?